# How to create a key value pair from a csv file considering the first column as key

Tags: scala

I have a csv file containing data like :

```
key1,value1,value2,value3  
key2,value1,value2,value3  
key3,value1,value2,value3
```

I am able to read the file in scala but nothing much after that.

```
val file = scala.io.Source.fromFile("filepath").getLines.toList
file: List[String] = List(key1,value1,value2,value3, key2,value1,value2,value3, key3,value1,value2,value3)
```

I want the output to be like :

`Map(key1->value1),Map(key1->value2),Map(key1->value3),Map(key2->value1)`...and so on`

Comment: The keys in a `Map` are required to be distinct. If you had duplicate key values what would `map(key1)` return? `value1` or `value2` or `value3`?

Comment: I have modified the expected output, the end goal here is to create a `key -> value` pair for each cell of the input file where the 1st column will be the key and the other column will be the value for that key.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is a fixed layout, you can turn your `files` value into key/value pairs like this:

```
val kv = file
  .grouped(4)
  .flatMap{
    case List(k, v1, v2, v3) => List(k -> v1, k ->v2, k -> v3)
  }.toList
```

This gives

```
List((key1,value1), (key1,value2), (key1,value3), (key2,value1), (key2,value2), (key2,value3), (key3,value1), (key3,value2), (key3,value3))
```

Your final output looks odd because it is just a list of single-entry `Map`s, but if this is really what you want then it just needs a simple `map` call:

```
kv.map(x => Map(x))
```

---

#### Update

If there is a variable number of values on each line then you need to process each line separately, something like this:

```
val src = scala.io.Source.fromFile("filepath")
val res =
  src.getLines.toList.flatMap { line =>
    line.split(",").toList match {
      case key :: values =>
        values.map(v => key -> v)
      case _ =>
        Nil
    }
  }
src.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the answer, I tried running this but getting below error. Also could you please suggest in more generic way considering the number of columns in the file can vary i.e. it does not have a fixed layout.`val kv = file.grouped(4).flatMap{case List(k, v1, v2, v3) => List(k -> v1, k ->v2, k -> v3)}.toList
scala.MatchError: List(key1,value1,value2,value3, key2,value1,value2,value3, key3,value1,value2,value3) (of class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$c
olon)`

Comment: I have added a version that copes with different numbers of columns in each line. It still remains unclear why you want a list of single-entry `Map`s.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code, Regd. the `Map` usage I am doing a exercise where I have to compare two files data(expected to contain similar set of records) and find out the differences if any. So what I am trying to do is to create the key value pair for each cell(considering the 1st column as key and rest of the columns are value) and then perform a comparison on top of that. I am not sure if this is a feasible way to do so, please do share the logic in case you have any better one.